# Setting PHP variable in <noscript>

Tags: javascript, php, noscript

Something like the below does not work:

```
<?php $nojs = false; ?>
<noscript>
    <?php $nojs = true; ?>
</noscript>
```

As the PHP is executed regardless if JS is enabled or not. But is there a way to get a similar effect? I'm trying to set a flag if JS is disabled and then display parts of the page accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is executed before javascript, so you cannot do this. You can do something such as executing a basic ajax request and storing `hasjs` in a session variable once the ajax page is successfully queried. You wouldn't know if it's just the fact that the ajax request wasn't successful due to something else, or if they have Javascript disabled.

Lets give this a shot anyway:

### The jquery script in your head tags

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.get( "hasjs.php", { hasjs: "1"} );
});
</script>
```

### The PHP file (hasjs.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['hasjs']))
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['hasjs'] = 1;
}
?>
```

Then you can access the session variable to determine if they have JS based off the ajax query. Nothing stopping the user from visiting that page though if they don't have JS installed.

Comment: The session variable is then stored for the session, what if the user disabled Javascript yet keeps the session alive? edit; I guess I could set a PHP flag based on the $_SESSION value then unset the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: You would set `hasjs` to 0 at the end of your PHP processing per page. The only way you would have issues is if the person disabled JS after page load. As far as I know, not much can really be done about this though. You can make it so that your content loads based off JS so that they have a really bad time if they try disable it. E.g. Submission of forms done VIA JS/AJAX etc